# Disable relayjs garbage collection

Tags: relayjs, relay, relaymodern

Is there a way to disable the relayjs garbage collection (version 5.0.0 or 6.0.0)?

We are still using relayjs classic and it caches all data in a session. This makes loading previous pages fast while fetching new data. In relayjs 5.0.0 they have a dataFrom on the QueryRenderer that can be set to "STORE_THEN_NETWORK" which will try the relay cache store first and fetch from the network, just like rejay classic. Except that the newer versions of relay uses a garbage collection feature to remove data that is not currently used. This makes almost all pages fetch data from the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working. The key thing here is the `environment.retain(operation.root);` which will retain the objects in the cache.

Then in the `QueryRenderer` use the `fetchPolicy="store-and-network"`.

See my full Relay Environment file below.

```
import {Environment, Network, RecordSource, Store} from 'relay-runtime';

function fetchQuery(operation, variables) {
    const environment = RelayEnvironment.getInstance();
    environment.retain(operation.root);

    return fetch(process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: operation.text,
            variables
        })
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    });
}

const RelayEnvironment = (function() {
    let instance;

    function createInstance() {
        return new Environment({
            network: Network.create(fetchQuery),
            store: new Store(new RecordSource())
        });
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function() {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

export default RelayEnvironment;
```

Also got this from the Relay Slack Channel. Haven't tried it yet.

```
const store = new Store(new RecordSource());
(store as any).holdGC(); // Disable GC on the store.
```